# like button launch site in unsuitable language

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-sdk-3.14.x

I have an app with a Facebook likeview button, when pressed it launches my Facebook promotional page in English language, but the audience's language is Spanish. How can I set it accordingly?. There's few items that one\ can set in accord to their [developer page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/LikeView). I'm using facebookSDK 3.23.1

Did you fix this issue?

Comment: What promotional page?

Comment: my site m.facebook.com/JuyDroid-1448302695432740. The text in button like and the information about how many like my site is in English language. The information about my facebook site is viewed in English too. The users of my app speak in Spanish. How can show like button and all information in Spanish?

Comment: The Facebook page will be in the language of the user.

Comment: my fb page is OK in desktop computer, but in my app it is shown in EN language, despite my local settings language of the device is in Spanish :-/

Comment: Does the page open in the native app or in the mobile browser? What is the app's language (it can differ from the system language)?

Comment: I have the same problem.
If FB app is installed, everything is in English. If is not installed buttons are in device language